# For loop and getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, getelementbyid

Hopefully an easy one, but I am having trouble printing out a number series from a for loop, back to the HTML. See below for my code, when I hit the button, it only returns 10, but not the rest of the numbers - where am I going wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try It</button>
    <p id="number"></p>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        for (i=0; i<11; i++) {
            document.getElementById("number").innerHTML=i+"</br>";
        } 
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("number").innerHTML += i+"</br>";`

Comment: it's because everytime you run through your loop you are setting it to i+"<br/>"... you need to concatenate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're *replacing* the element's contents on each loop. If you want to *add to* the contents, use `+=` rather than `=` (as a minimal change):

```
document.getElementById("number").innerHTML+=i+"</br>";
// here -----------------------------------^
```

That said, I wouldn't do that, because it's making the browser do a lot of unnecessary work under the covers. *Every time* you read the value of `innerHTML`, the browser has to spin through the element and build up a string representing its contents; and *every time* you write to `innerHTML`, it has to parse the HTML, wipe out previous elements, and build new ones.

Instead, consider building up a string and doing *one* assignment:

```
function myFunction() {
    var i, s = "";
    for (i=0; i<11; i++) {
        s += i + "<br>";
    } 
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = s;
}
```

---

Side note 1: Your code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) because you're not declaring `i`. I've fixed that above by declaring it.

Side note 2: `</br>` is an invalid tag. In HTML, it's `<br>` (or `<br/>`; the ending `/` is **entirely** optional). In XHTML, it's `<br/>`.

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById("number").innerHTML=i+"</br>";
```

will replace the HTML of `number`, change it to

```
document.getElementById("number").innerHTML+=i+"</br>";// see the `+`
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting .innerHTML with = completely changes its content.
Use += to append content.

```
document.getElementById("number").innerHTML += i + "</br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since most of the other answers have shown you the error, here's an edit of your code that shows how you can get the result you want but without hitting the DOM with each iteration of the loop:

```
function myFunction() {

    // create an array
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {

        // push the data to the array
        arr.push(i + '<br/>');
    }

    // grab the element and then add the joined array to the html
    document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = arr.join('');
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2g4xodwo/)